# How can I calculate the points of two lines that connect two circles?

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

Let's say I have two circles of equal or differing radii, a variable distance apart.

[image: Two Circles]

I want to calculate the end points of two lines, that will "connect" the circles.

[image: Two Connected Circles]

And no matter how the circles may be oriented, they should still "connect" in the same way.

[image: Two Connect Circles at a Different Angle]

How can I calculate the end points of these two lines?

Comment: Do you mean the lines to be tangents? Or do they join the endpoints of the diameters which are perpendicular to the line joining the centres of the two circles?

Comment: @MarkBennet That's a good question.  I'm not sure which I would prefer.

Comment: Assuming the former, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_lines_to_circles#Tangent_lines_to_two_circles

Comment: Posing a question whose precise formulation you’re not sure of?

Comment: I've thought it though, and yes, I'd like the lines to be tangents.

Answer (score 1):

1. From your question, I assume that the equations of these two circles are known (and are called C1 and C2).
2. From C1 and C2, the co-ordinates of the centers are known.
3. Find m the slope of the line joining the centers.
4. The slope of the diameter (the one perpendicular to the line of centers) on C1 (and also on C2, because they are parallel) = -1/m.
5. Use point-slope form to find L1, the equation of the diameter of C1.
6. Solve C1 and L1 to obtain two sets of values for your answer.
7. Do the similar thing on steps 4 and 5 to obtain another set of answer for points on C2.

Answer (score 0):

In either way if you know the circles find gradient of circle meaning y' and equate them so you get the line.

"this line will be tangent since they are not cutting circle"

Note: To joint endpoint of diameter they must be of equal radii and in any case the above method will get you result.